# Rails 5 with psql db - deploying AWS elastic beanstalk - renders blank white page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I gave up trying to learn how to work with AWS years ago. I let $$$$ credits lapse (no one answered tech support requests when I was last trying) and I used heroku. I've been using heroku for years - with no problem, other than I want to try using AWS to see if it reduces the cost.  However, I've spent all of the last 2 days trying to figure out how to setup my rails 5 app (with psql db) on AWS elastic beanstalk and I'm ready to run away again.

On the AWS dashboard, I get a green light, with no errors showing. I use the link to the page on the dashboard, and it renders an empty white page. The logs say:

```
Command processor should execute command.
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.347Z] DEBUG [4608]  : Storing current stage..
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.347Z] DEBUG [4608]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Return
ing..


[2016-10-05T03:23:47.705Z] INFO  [4608]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.705Z] INFO  [4608]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.705Z] INFO  [4608]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.705Z] INFO  [4608]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2016-10-05T03:23:47.706Z] INFO  [4608]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2016-10-05T08:36:22.133Z] INFO  [32010] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2016-10-05T08:36:22.133Z] INFO  [32010] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2016-10-05T08:36:22.133Z] INFO  [32010] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2016-10-05T08:36:22.133Z] INFO  [32010] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2016-10-05T08:36:22.133Z] INFO  [32010] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log-20161003.gz
-------------------------------------
requested file /var/log/nginx/access.log-20161003.gz is not a supported file type, please use bundle log to download the complete file...


-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
-------------------------------------
172.31.5.178 - - [05/Oct/2016:03:53:02 +0000] "GET /admin/i18n/readme.txt HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64" "173.231.185.150"
172.31.28.72 - - [05/Oct/2016:03:53:28 +0000] "GET /admin/i18n/readme.txt HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64" "173.231.185.150"
:
```

It goes on and on with things I can't make any sense of. Ive spent the day watching you tube clips, following tutorials and trying to figure this out. There must be a way to get this working.

Please can anyone see what I need to do solve these errors?  I'll give up and stick with heroku, but am really feeling defeated that AWS is so inaccessible.

Comment: PS: learning AWS is too hard. I'm sticking with heroku. I can't waste any more time on this.

Comment: I deployed a Rails 5 app to EB last week. It works and should be that hard. Your logs mention Python. Which seems odd if you are trying to use Rails 5. If you share more info you'll get help.  First thing I would check is your platform. Make sure you are using Ruby 2.x with either Puma or Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this gem : https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk
Another thing is - im not that sure beanstalk fully support Rails 5 yet, 
by that reason you should try with Rails version 4.2
for Postgresql -> https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your frustration, Elastic Beanstalk’s initial setup can be frustrating at times, especially when you’re coming off such an easy-to-use platform as Heroku.

The good news is that after the initial setup, the day-to-day operations are pretty similar to the process you use to host your applications on Heroku.

Here are a few tips that may help you increase your productivity when you migrating from Heroku to Elastic Beanstalk:

### 1) Use the multicontainer Docker environment

Based on Docker’s current popularity, it’s pretty safe bet to assume you’re already familiar with Docker. If that’s the case for you, using Elastic Beanstalk’s multicontainer Docker environment can simplify the migration dramatically.

Instead of investing hours learning how Elastic Beanstalk’s different stacks are configured, “just” make a Docker container run locally with your application. From there, it’s pretty easy to make the application run on Elastic Beanstalk.

The multicontainer Docker environment is built on top of ECS (Elastic Container Service) and includes its own Docker image registry. Everything you need to build and run your Dockerized application on Elastic Beanstalk is included and can be integrated pretty easily.

### 2) Use the herokuish Docker image

Unfortunately, you can never be sure which dependencies you will need to install on your Docker image to make your application run smoothly. It’s easy to waste hours tinkering your Dockerfile to make your application work properly.

A more efficient option is to use a herokuish command line utility to build a Docker container that emulates Heroku’s stack.

The final image might be slightly bigger than you would expect, but the time you’ll save by using the image instead of re-inventing the wheel is worth the additional few megabytes. You can always switch to a smaller image when you feel more comfortable with Elastic Beanstalk.

### 3) Migrate the database last

This suggestion might be obvious for some, but migrating your PostgreSQL database to AWS can be a stressful and fragile task. I think it’s a good idea to do the database migration last, just before you feel ready to shut down your Heroku account.

### Conclusion

I’ll admit that Elastic Beanstalk’s learning curve can be stiff at times -- especially if you don’t have prior experience with AWS. Docker can simplify things, and worrying about the database migration last can simplify things even more. It’s also important to have plan the migration and start the process with a small POC.

If you would like to give Elastic Beanstalk and AWS another try, here’s more information about how I approached similar Heroku to AWS migrations before: [Migrate from Heroku to AWS Safely and Seamlessly](https://opsfleet.com/topics/migrate-from-heroku-to-aws/migration-steps/)

Hope that helps.